# Using forms Auth with existing database in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, security, forms-authentication

MVC3 web app tied to db on SQL Server 2012.  This will be a public facing web site hosted by a third party.

I am new to using forms authentication.  I created a project in VS 2012 a couple months ago using the default Internet Template, so I have the standard accountcontroller, etc.  I noticed it built a new empty database called aspnet-MyAppName-bunch of numbers. I assume it is for the userprofile table, etc.

I am wondering if I should just go with it.  I had already built a user table in my existing database, and I built a class using the Crypto library to hash and store the password, and create the user account.  I am implementing the forms auth for inter-app security, i.e to make sure people are authorized to view the members only pages.

What do I need to do to integrate my existing validateUser class with Forms Auth?
If I want to have all the user security stuff in my existing database, do I just change the connection string somewhere?  or is there more to it?

Like I said, i am new to Forms Auth, so if I am trying to do really weird stuff and should just keep it as is, let me know.  Thanks.

====EDIT=======

Theanks Zach.  I started looking this over and as I want the membership tables in my existing db, I ran the asp_regsql.exe, which add the tables.  I need to add a relationship between the membership user table and some of the existing tables, but all my ID columns are int and all the membership tables are uniqueidentifers, which wont relate.  My existing tables have content in them.  I tried changing the uniqueidentifiers but it wont work, even tried droping the constraints, then the tables but the constraints wouldn't drop, saying they aren't constraints.  Any idea how to successfully mate the new membership tabls to my existing?

Comment: what I suggested you, was a custom membership, so you don't needed extra tables, the idea of a custom membership provider is work beside your existing security struct

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is the Mempership provider

in your web.config specify authentication mode and your custom membership provider

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" 
        type="CustomMembership.Models.CustomMembershipProvider"
        connectionStringName=""
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
        requiresUniqueEmail="false"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
```

A short example to build your custom membership, there is a lot of aditional function that you can extend

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        //all your logic to validate the user credentials to your custom db
    }

}
```

NOTE: this is just a short example, to get the entire documentation of membership provider see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx

and a complete example you can find here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75(v=vs.100).aspx